# Have a SQL statement that is executing twice on IIS but once in Visual Studio, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a SQL statement that executes twice when posted to the IIS, but it only executes once when in Visual Studio; I am not sure why it works in one but not the other.

Some other information I have a wildcard SSL that is attached to the server, and I only see one post request in the network Log. The actual code ( with some changes to protect the identity of the site. )

```
public void AddMenuLink(MenuLinks m)
{
    string sql = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (Href, Target, IsF, Name, MenuGroup)" +
                 " VALUES (@Href, @Target, @IsF, @Name, @MenuGroup)"; 

    ConnHelper misc = new ConnHelper();
    SqlConnection Conn = null;
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = null;

    try
    {
            Conn = misc.GetDataConnection();

            sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Conn);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Href", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = m.Href;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Target", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  m.Target;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Iswolf", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = m.IsF;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = m.Name;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@MenuGroup", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = m.MenuGroup;

            sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            Conn.Close();
        }
}
```

The code that calls it is:

```
if (Request.Form["Add"] == "Add") 
{
    MenuLinks M = new MenuLinks();
    // Check if upload
    int uploadFlag = 0;

    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
                uploadFlag = 1;
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

                try
                {
                    //Original and used for viewing
                    string pathing = FILE_SHARE + "\\";
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathing);
                    var path = Path.Combine(pathing, file.FileName);
                    file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(pathing, fileName));

                    //Backup
                    string pathing2 = BACKUP_SHARE + "\\";
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathing2);
                    var path2 = Path.Combine(pathing2, file.FileName);
                    file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(pathing2, fileName));

                    //save path in database get ID.
                    M.Href = "http://MYSITE/Content/" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(file.FileName);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ViewBag.error = ex.ToString();
                    ViewBag.error += " Saving File FAILED IN ADD";
                    uploadFlag = 2;
                }
            }

            if(uploadFlag == 0)
            {
                //if there is no upload href get the one from link
                M.Href = Request.Form["Href"];
            }

            M.Target = Request.Form["Target"];
            M.Name = Request.Form["Name"];
            M.IsF = Request.Form["IsF"];
            M.MenuGroup = Request.Form["MenuGroup"];

            // filter uploads
            if (uploadFlag != 2)
            {
                DB.AddMenuLink(M);
            }
}
```

There are three forms in the view, add/edit/delete.

In the view I have this (Add section only):

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>File Upload</p>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br />
<p>Link (leave blank if uploading file)</p>
<input type="text" name="Href" id="href" /><br />
<p>Target</p>
<select name="Target" id="Target">
    <option value="_self">In frame</option>

    <option value="_blank">New window</option>
</select>   

    <br />
<p>Name</p>
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" /><br />
<p>Tagged For:</p>
<input type="radio" name="IsF" value="Both" checked />Both<br />
<input type="radio" name="IsF" value="0"  />One<br />
<input type="radio" name="IsF" value="1" />The Other<br />

<br />
<p>Menu Group</p>
<select name="MenuGroup" id="MenuGroup">
    @{


        x.MenuGroup = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            x.getMenuGroup(i);
            if (x.MenuGroup != "")
            {
                @Html.Raw("<option value='" + x.MenuGroup + "'>" + x.MenuGroup + "</option>")
                x.MenuGroup = "";
            }
        }
    }
</select>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Add" name="Add" />
</form>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what file is the "The code that calls it is" sitting? I am thinking that this code gets called once when the app pool is started and then another when the view is being accessed by the user.

Comment: All DB editing code is in a class called CodeDB, The code that calls it is the home controller.  The view calls the controller, the controller calls the class.  This is the only instance in the home controller where DB.addmenulink() is called.  I am starting to think this might be an issue on the server side, I am going to try and clean rebuild and publish.    EDIT:  That did it, I guess I needed to clean my project to fix it weird.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a clean/rebuild/republish issue with IIS.